# rails redirects to 'data:,'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app, I'm saving an input of HTML as a 'page' like so:

```
def create
  @page = Page.new(page_params)
  @page.unique = loop do
     random_unique = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(4)
     break random_unique unless Page.where(unique: random_unique).exists?
   end

  @page.save
  redirect_to "/#{@page.unique}"
end
```

but if you include functionality in the  tags, it says it's rendered the page, but in fact it returns nothing, with the URL bar showing 'data:,'

Strangely, if you find the @page.unique, and visit it afterwards, e.g. localhost:3000/SKkFrA the page renders fine.

Any suggestions?

p.s. Here's the show method I'm using:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by(unique: params[:id])
  render :text => @page.html
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on IRC.

This is a security feature, the HTML content of the new page matches the HTML content of the submitted form, which Chrome blocks.

Comment: so you are free to select your own answer :-)

Comment: So what's the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I'll second @pixelearth ... what's the answer? Is there a workaround? I have the same problem! There's more discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106111/rails-4-redirects-to-data-in-chrome) but no resolution.

Comment: I have the same problem too!

Comment: @pixelearth I never found a solution. The URL was still created though, so my 'workaround' was just copy-pasting this off elsewhere. I only really made the project for my own use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the reasons mention by OP - "This is a security feature, the HTML content of the new page matches the HTML content of the submitted form, which Chrome blocks".

The solution for me was to no longer out the html data on show page.  I could get away with this because my instance is a backend app that did not require the html to be visible, just needs to be in the db.