# Rails 4 redirects to 'data:,' in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a weird behavior in Google Chrome, which is also described in this question: [rails redirects to 'data:,'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620118/rails-redirects-to-data)

When a new resource is being created and my controller redirects to the show action, **chrome initiates loading of a blank page with `'data:,'` in the address bar**. The reply of the author who asked the above mentioned question is the following:

*This is a security feature, the HTML content of the new page matches the HTML content of the submitted form, which Chrome blocks.*

However no explanation of how to fix it followed. The behavior is only present in Chrome browser.

Comment: If anyone knows, I'm also curious about the security part of this. Why does Chrome consider this a security feature?

Comment: I already had a similar problem . Google Chrome cache 301 redirects. You'll just need to clear your browser cache or develop with incognito mode. http://bugsquash.blogspot.fr/2008/12/google-chrome-caches-301-redirects.html solved by

Comment: Can you post the action that causes this, as well as any possible trace info for that action?

Comment: BTW ... clearing cache or using incognito is *not* a solution. I have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530292/why-is-my-rails-app-redirecting-to-data) and this advice didn't help. Still looking for an actual answer.

Comment: +1 Met this "feature" as well.  For me it was slightly more baffling, but seemed to relate to security.  I'm updating a CMS field where the user can enter `<script>` tags for tracking codes and the like.  This "feature" will *only* kick in if the `<script>` tag has content inside it.  Other tags e.g. `<style>` will not trigger the redirect.  Empty `<script>` tags (whitespace or not) will not trigger the redirect.

Comment: You should post the code where you are returning the response. It's possible that the code is not formatted correctly in the respond_to block. Also, if you are doing a redirect through javascript, then post that block of code as well.

Comment: I suspect `render :text => @page.html` should be `render :text => html_safe(@page.html)`. What does Chrome Debug Network (w/Preserve) say? What happens when you submit a `curl` or `wget` request? I think `data:,` might be part of a malformed HTTP header.

Comment: Same issue on Safari yields this error message. "The XSS Auditor blocked access to 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/forums/3/topics/3' because the source code of a script was found within the request. The server sent an 'X-XSS-Protection' header requesting this behavior".

Answer (score 10):

I've been googling it and found that editing posts with an iframe in Rails 4.0 causes a redirect to "data:,"

> Rails 4 now sets the X-XSS-Protection header for all requests, so the iframe trips up the XSS protection in Chrome after a form submit.
>   (https://github.com/elektronaut/sugar/issues/41#issuecomment-25987368)

Solution, add it to your controller:

```
before_filter :disable_xss_protection

protected
def disable_xss_protection
  # Disabling this is probably not a good idea,
  # but the header causes Chrome to choke when being
  # redirected back after a submit and the page contains an iframe.
  response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = "0"
end
```

Comment: I can confirm that doing this "resolves" the issue. Though I agree it is probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know what this is. You can specify images and text inside a data: protocol, and I believe Chrome is seeing escaped HTML and thinking it is data. Since the mime type is not specified, it leaves the mime type blank after the colon, and just prints the comma.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection

Rails 4 automatically escapes HTML, so if you are trying to render HTML, you have to indicate not to escape it. Look at the options for render:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection

You can use `raw()` to render direct HTML.

http://www.webbydude.com/posts/9-the-h-helper-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced it is related to a mimetype issue. I have this issue when a user posts a blog entry that has iframes in its content. When the entry is saved it redirects to the "show" action which will have the user's content (raw/html_safe). Chrome will display the page for a split second and then for some reason re-direct again to the blank "data:," page (in history it will only leave the data:, and the submit page).

here are the response headers i registered:

Ruby 2.0.0 / Rails 4 migrated app with incorrect behavior (staging server)

```
    Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:25359
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Thu, 23 Jan 2014 16:37:11 GMT
    ETag:"6d9d4961ea2df12de67f8a92c43579fb"
    Server:Apache
    Set-Cookie: _**********_session_dev=1774518c571bf4e65189d607b276e65e; domain=*********.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 23 Jan 2014 18:37:11 -0000; HttpOnly
    Status:200 OK
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
    X-Mod-Pagespeed:1.6.29.7-3566
    X-Request-Id:9f5314a5-ad01-4aec-bd0f-04e8afd9bdac
    X-UA-Compatible:chrome=1
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2 app with correct behavior (prod server)

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 23 Jan 2014 16:32:53 GMT
    Server: Apache
    ETag: "f12135ddd373205352f9754328368217"
    Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Status: 200
    X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.4.26.5-3533
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Length: 27167
    X-Cnection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Encoding: gzip
```

also tried having this as the initial html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>...
```

and also just (as random tests to detect what could be wrong)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>...
```

All I know is that if the submitted content has iframes, when redirecting to the blog "display" page chrome's weird behavior kicks in.