# Why is my Rails app redirecting to `data:,`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ace-editor

So when I save a record in my Rails 4 app this happens. Here's some details:

- I'm using the [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about).
- The `data` attribute is no where in my model or app.
- The form is a standard `form_for` (not remote).
- The record does save successfully but then it redirects to this weird ass URL.

The code for the update is standard scaffold boilerplate.

```
# PATCH/PUT /pages/1
# PATCH/PUT /pages/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @page.update(page_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone have any ideas? Probably something simple but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. Let me know if there's any other pertinent information I can share.

Comment: I forgot ... I recorded a Quickcast of it which can be seen [here](http://quick.as/elxrckdb).

Comment: Can you add log output when this happens?

Comment: how are you setting up the `@page` variable? Could it be that it's not a Page class, which would cause the first `redirect_to` to not know where to go?

Comment: Maybe this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620118/rails-redirects-to-data

Comment: @page = Page.find(params[:id]) don't you miss the var declaration?

Comment: @ThyagoB.Rodrigues :: Holy crud ... I searched and searched. Quoted, with tags, etc. and that link didn't show up. Unfortunately, there is no answer there so I'm unsure of how to work around the Chrome security "feature".

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé :: the instance variable is being set by a before_action filter ala:

`before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: Also found a mention of this bug [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106111/rails-4-redirects-to-data-in-chrome) but still no solution. Clearing cache and incognito mode didn't help (and aren't much of a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case (the one shown in your quickcast), Chrome is considering this a security risk because you're submitting a `<script>` element containing javascript that's being inserted into the renderable contents of the page *using* [Rails' built-in] asynchronous javascript.

To avoid this, you could:

1. Strip out the wrapping `<script>` tags using client-side logic before submitting the form, and then add them back in on the server before saving the record.
2. Disable Rails' built-in ajaxification of the update action in this controller, so that it submits through plain old HTML
3. Add an intermediary redirect page between form submittal and viewing the show action

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because your @page `show` view is rendering escaped HTML and Javascript. Chrome probably has heuristics to analyze the page and determine what type of document it is. Since it likely doesn't start with `<html>`, then Chrome assumes it is a data file with the `data:` protocol. Try rendering to a string and printing the results on the console:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

```
puts render_to_string @page
```

See section 4.1.1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection

```
data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgnWFNTJyk8L3NjcmlwdD4K
```

Please update your answer with the show view template, the show action, and the log from `render_to_string`.